# Data through Sockets in C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, serialization, tcp

I am currently working on a project that uses the network. I have to send a struct

```
    struct Header
    {
     uint32_t   magic;
     uint32_t   checksum;
     uint32_t   timestamp;
     uint16_t   commandId;
     uint16_t   dataSize;
    };

    struct Packet
    {
     struct Header  header;
     char       data[128];
    };
```

I'm trying to send the struct Packet from one socket to another using TCP. I've tried to send my struct like that

```
      send(socket, &my_struct, sizeof(my_struct), 0);
```

but it is not working so I've tried to serialize my struct into a char*

```
unsigned char               *Serialization::serialize_uint32(unsigned char *buffer, uint32_t arg)
{
 buffer[3] = (arg >> 24);
 buffer[2] = (arg >> 16);
 buffer[1] = (arg >> 8);
 buffer[0] = (arg);
 return (buffer + sizeof(uint32_t));
}

unsigned char               *Serialization::serialize_uint16(unsigned char *buffer, uint16_t arg)
{
 buffer[1] = (arg >> 8);
 buffer[0] = (arg);
 return (buffer + sizeof(uint16_t));
}

    unsigned char                           *Serialization::deserialize_uint32(unsigned char *buffer, uint32_t *arg)
    {
      memcpy((char*)arg, buffer, sizeof(uint32_t));
      return (buffer + sizeof(uint32_t));
    }

    unsigned char                           *Serialization::deserialize_uint16(unsigned char *buffer, uint16_t *arg)
    {
     memcpy((char*)arg, buffer, sizeof(uint16_t));
     return (buffer + sizeof(uint16_t));
    }
```

even when a client symply send a struct Header data is corrupt when I read it server side
Why is the data corrupt ?

Client sending loop

```
    TcpSocket                     tcp;
    Packet                        p;
    std::stringstream             ss;
    int                           cpt = 0;
    int                           ret = 0;
    char                          *serialized;

    tcp.connectSocket("127.0.0.1", 4242);
    while (getchar())
    {
      ss.str("");
      ss.clear();
  ss << cpt++;
  p.header.magic = 0;
  p.header.checksum = 1;
  p.header.timestamp = 2;
  p.header.commandId = 3;
  p.header.dataSize = ss.str().length();
  memset(p.data, 0, 128);
  memcpy(p.data, ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().length());
  serialized = new char[sizeof(Header) + ss.str().length()];
  bzero(serialized, sizeof(Header) + ss.str().length());
  Serialization::serialize_packet(serialized, p);
  hexDump("serialized", serialized+1, sizeof(Header) + ss.str().length());
  ret = tcp.write(serialized+1, sizeof(Header) + ss.str().length());
}
```

server recv loop: (fonction call by select() )

```
  buff = new char[bav];
  socket->read(buff, bav);
  hexdump("buff", buff, bav);
```

socket->read() :

```
    int                     TcpSocket::read(char *buff, int len)
    {
      int                   ret;

      ret = recv(this->_socket, buff, len, 0);
      return (ret);
    }
```

when I run those programs :

```
    ./server
    [Server] new connexion :: [5]
    recv returns : 17
    buff serialized:
      0000  00 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 1c 00 00 00 1a 00 00 00  ................
      0010  1b

    ./client
    serialized data:
      0000  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 03 00 01 30  ...............0
      0010  00
    send returns : 17
```

Comment: Are we to assume the client is unpacking this in a proper reverse algorithm (and note you should be using `unsigned char` for your pack buffer). Also, your structure packing in the first case as well as machine endian format *will* come into play.

Comment: For uint16 and uint32, you can just use ntohl, ntohs, htonl, and htons. The short answer is this: You must precisely define your data format at the byte level and correctly convert to and from that "wire format" when you send and receive.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I concur, but when I proffered that up as a solution a couple of days ago for a similar problem I was summarily jumped one-side and down the other because it wasn't in "the standard". Still stinging from that one.(I'd still do it with the POSIX functions regardless, btw, just as you probably would).

Comment: There are two obvious problems. First, send(socket, &my_struct, sizeof(my_struct)) will not work because send() takes _four_ arguments. Second, the serialization should be using unsigned char (i.e. 'byte') instead of char.  As has been pointed out, the 'network' functions to obviate endian-ness issues are even better.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Since this question is tagged `C` and `C++` and uses `uint32_t`, I can't imagine what "the standard" would be. :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz " You must precisely define your data format at the byte level and correctly convert to and from that "wire format" 
Could you please write me a little exemple, I don't really understand how to use htonl, htons and ntohl, ntohs.

Comment: "it is not working" — how do you know it is not working?  What is happening?  What is supposed to happen?

Comment: because when I hexdump the data received server side, it is different that the one I've sent with the client

Comment: That's interesting -- can you provide the hex dumps, since they're short?

Comment: client send : 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 03 00 01 30  ...............0
server recv : 00 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 1c 00 00 00 1a 00 00 00  ................

Comment: The problem is in your network code.  Show us how you use `recv()`, there is probably an error in how it's being called.  (There's possibly an error in `send()` too, but errors in `recv()` are more straightforward.)  Don't just show the call to `recv()`, show us the surrounding loop.  If there is no loop, you are using `recv()` wrong.

Comment: let me 5 minutes i'll edit my post in order to add the recv loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, this is wrong, and it will definitely cause errors.

```
buff = new char[bav];
socket->read(buff, bav);
hexdump("buff", buff, bav);
socket->read() :

int TcpSocket::read(char *buff, int len)
{
    return recv(this->_socket, buff, len, 0);
}
```

## The return value from `recv()` must not be ignored.

From `man 2 recv`:

```
RETURN VALUES
     These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error
     occurred.

     For TCP sockets, the return value 0 means the peer has closed its half
     side of the connection.
```

So, how many bytes did you receive?  It's impossible to tell, if you discard the result from `recv()`.  Maybe `recv()` failed, you'd never find out if you don't check the return value.  Maybe it only filled up part of your buffer.  *You have to check the return code from `recv()`.*  This is the number one error people make when writing programs that use TCP.

You will need to alter your code to handle the following cases:

1. The `recv()` call may completely fill your buffer.
2. The `recv()` call may partially fill your buffer.
3. The `recv()` call may return 0, indicating that the sender has shut down the connection.
4. The `recv()` call may indicate `EINTR` because it was interrupted by a system call.
5. The `recv()` call may indicate `ECONNRESET` because the sender has closed the connection suddenly or has disappeared.
6. The `recv()` call may encounter some other error.

Remember: when using TCP, just because you `send()` 16 bytes doesn't mean that the other peer will `recv()` 16 bytes — it may be broken up into chunks.  TCP is a stream protocol.  Unlike UDP, adjacent chunks of data can be arbitrarily joined or split.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I think it's fine without bold.

Comment: my client send return is 17, and my server recv return is 17 too :(

Comment: @CamilleTolsa: I think you misunderstood.  There is no point in telling me what the return value is, because **the return value may be different every time.**  You must modify your program so that it behaves correctly for every return value `recv()` can give.

Comment: I understand but, I use a circularbuffer to handle case [1] & [2], case [3] is handle to, case [4], [5] or [6] never happens in my tests.

Comment: @CamilleTolsa: Try running client and server with Valgrind.  Since you haven't posted the fixed code that handles at least cases 1 and 2, I have no way of knowing if it is correct or not.

Comment: If you don't handle these cases it will blow up sooner or later, this is a classic mistake that people seem to think that they can "get away" with

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to mask only the low 8 bits each time:

   ```
   buffer[3] = (arg >> 24) & 0xff;
   buffer[2] = (arg >> 16) & 0xff;
   buffer[1] = (arg >> 8) & 0xff;
   buffer[0] = (arg) & 0xff;
   ```
2. Do the same when you deserialize

Comment: can you explain me why please

Comment: Because `buffer` may be signed.

Comment: **This answer is wrong.**  Masking here doesn't do anything on any platform with 8-bit bytes.  Since `arg` and `buffer` are both unsigned, all arithmetic is modular according to the C standard.  So if `x` has type `unsigned char`, and if `unsigned char` has 8 bits, then `x = arg` and `x = arg & 0xff` produce exactly the same results.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - when the answer was given, the question specified that Buffer is signed, the question was editted 2 hours after the answer.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet: Sure, but even if it is signed, it won't make a difference on two's-complement platforms, e.g., all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would not reinvent the wheel.  There are a lot of well documented and tested libraries / protocols out there for exactly the purpose you are looking for.  A small list which just comes to my mind:

- [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)
- [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
- JSON
- XML
- CORBA

Comment: I know but I'm working on a school project and we are not allowed to use any libraries and we must not use a text protocol :(

Comment: Please define 'library'? Is the C-Library a library? (E.g. are you allowed to use htonX / ntohX functions?)

Comment: we are allowed to use the libc htons/htonl & ntohX are allowed, but I've nerver used them and I don't know how to